# Merge two overlapping DEM files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, merge, overlapping-features

I am trying to combine two overlapping DEM files in QGIS and I can't do it. Let's see if I can explain myself well with these photos, but I would like to use the DEM A as a base and fill it with the piece of the DEM B. Is it possible to do it?

What I have:

[image]

What I want:

[image]

Comment: "Is it possible?" questions miss the point of  StackExchange, which is to focus on "How is it possible?" Please [Edit] your Question to focus on what you have attempted to accomplish this task. Your graphics show you know it is in fact possible (several ways, in fact, though some are more laborious than necessary). So how have you attempted to identify the NODATA of A and use it to clip B and merge with A to form C? It can be done in one step with a `Con` expression in ArcGIS; imagine the same is true in QGIS.

Comment: Needlessly rude comments miss the point of StackExchange, which is to focus on ["kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/conduct). Please Edit your comment to focus on what would be helpful to the person asking the question and others who may find this page through search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

select in Toolbox[image]: gdal_merge. And merge your rasters